# Explore google protobuf in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

From dialogflows API I received a protobuf.
Even after reading all documentation I have no clue how to explore the object and extract values (e.g. a string out of it)

I show you what I did:

```
(Pdb) dir(parameter)
['ByteSize', 'Clear', 'ClearExtension', 'ClearField', 'CopyFrom', 'DESCRIPTOR', 'DiscardUnknownFields', 'Extensions', 'FieldsEntry', 'FindInitializationErrors', 'FromString', 'HasExtension', 'HasField', 'IsInitialized', 'ListFields', 'MergeFrom', 'MergeFromString', 'ParseFromString', 'RegisterExtension', 'SerializePartialToString', 'SerializeToString', 'SetInParent', 'UnknownFields', 'WhichOneof', '_CheckCalledFromGeneratedFile', '_SetListener', '__class__', '__contains__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '_extensions_by_name', '_extensions_by_number', 'fields', 'get_or_create_list', 'get_or_create_struct', 'items', 'keys', 'update', 'values']

(Pdb) parameter.ListFields
<built-in method ListFields of Struct object at 0x7f5e0c17e920>

(Pdb) parameter.ListFields()
[(<google.protobuf.pyext._message.FieldDescriptor object at 0x7f5e0c191a10>, {'endDate': string_value: "2019-07-31T23:59:59+02:00"
, 'startDate': string_value: "2019-07-01T00:00:00+02:00"
})]

(Pdb) parameter.endDate
*** AttributeError: endDate

(Pdb) parameter
fields {
  key: "endDate"
  value {
    string_value: "2019-07-31T23:59:59+02:00"
  }
}
fields {
  key: "startDate"
  value {
    string_value: "2019-07-01T00:00:00+02:00"
  }
}

(Pdb) parameter.fields
{'endDate': string_value: "2019-07-31T23:59:59+02:00"
, 'startDate': string_value: "2019-07-01T00:00:00+02:00"
}

(Pdb) type(parameter.fields)
<class 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.MessageMapContainer'>

(Pdb) parameter.fields.get('endDate')
string_value: "2019-07-31T23:59:59+02:00"
```

My goal is to extract `startDate` and `endDate`.

Can anybody help to explain how to systematically expore such an undocumented protobuf and get the values out of it?